# Random list with specific length and sum

Tags: python, list, random

I need a list of random floats with a sum of 1 and a certain length.

To my knowledge, the methods I have seen generate all possible scenarios, and it is possible that there are no lists with a specific length among the cases. Although making the remaining elements of the list equal to zero is an option, it doesn't seem like a good idea!

It is costly and time-consuming to just make this list by trial and error, so the program is time-consuming.

Comment: How about generating a list with random numbers and then "normalize" it, by dividing each element by the sum of the list?

Comment: Yeah, seems a good idea! thanks

Comment: But still, if there is a built-in function or some general functions, I would appreciate it if anyone can share it.

Comment: there is an infinity of possible answers. I just listed one that uses Normal(0,1) and @j1lee's idea of dividing by the sum. Are there any other requirements for your list?

Comment: @PierreD your and j1-Iee's answer already solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import numpy as np

n = 100
a = np.random.normal(size=n)
a /= a.sum()
```

After that:

```py
>>> a.sum()
0.9999999999999998
```

Note: if your list is short and you are worried of the absolutely exceptional case where the initial `a.sum()` be `0`, then:

```py
while True:
    a = np.random.normal(size=n)
    if not np.allclose(a.sum(), 0):
        a /= a.sum()
        break
```